# How can I prevent user from entering specific value using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a calculator. I've made a disabled textbox just below the buttons which return the values in order 0 to 9. I want my simply made calculator to detect when a user enters calculation signs first and occur an error there.

How can I achieve this by using JQuery? The code is pretty long so I've just created a [`JSfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7czyczbq/1/) here! Can you check it out please and any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why my question got flagged with the reason "why isn't this code working?"... I don't ask such question. What I'm trying to say is, I don't share code here because I don't have a code to share about my question. Because I just don't know how to do that. Well thanks for looking at my question anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work for your specific question, but you'll have a lot more cases to consider.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $entered = $('#entered');
    $('div > button').click(function() {
        var input = $(this).text();
        if (isNaN(input) && !$entered.val())
            alert('Invalid');
        else
            $entered.val($entered.val() + input);
    });
});
```

Other cases to consider:

- Prevent multiple operators in a row or operators being immediately before an equal
- Let = be a control instead of acting like an operator
- Preventing numbers from being too large for internal variables to do the math (20 numbers in a row before an operator - you'll need to lookup specific limits for your types)
- How to parse the entered to actual process the result (hint: eval)

At least with the code above, you only have one place to process input instead of 1 for each button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I'll have more problems with it but in the end, hopefully it'll worth it.

Comment: It's a good example to work through and learn from. Good luck!